# Windows Gamebar - how change capture bar position (coordinates)?

Tags: windows-10, xbox-game-dvr

How change capture bar position during capture by Win-Alt-R (see on screen on right side) or minimize bar or something?
[image]

Same question [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/game-recording-bar-position-adjusting-problem/cf53c192-75e0-4ead-a7ad-0416836cd0ca)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the overlay is active, you can simply hover the mouse over the controls. A titlebar will show, which you can use to drag the small window to a new position. Once you move the mouse away from that window element, the title for that window element will disappear too. This works for all windows, not just the record button window element.

To my knowledge, it is not possible to actually hide the recording toolbar once you start recording. Closing will end the recording.

This is what you see when you start to record from the game overlay (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). Notice the grayed background showing as the overlay is active.

[image]

In the overlay, if I hover the mouse over the recording window, notice how a titlebar becomes visible with an X button. You can drag this window to anywhere on the screen to alter its location, and it will stay there when you Escape out of the XBox Overlay.

[image]

Comment: From Microsoft Developers many many things - "it is not possible" :(

Comment: I have succesfully moved the icon, but every attempt I do to minimize the button results in the recording stopping.

Comment: *>A titlebar will show* - for me not show absolutely. Can you give screen? Maybe dependents on the version of Windows.

Comment: I've added a before and after screenshot for your convenience. Do note, you HAVE to be in the overlay to move the control.

Comment: Thank, but titlebar in my case really don't appear . I'm don't know why...

Comment: The XBox overlay is an app you can download from the windows store. Maybe you have an older version. See if deleting it and then getting it from the windows store fixes the issue.

Comment: Ok, will try...

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood, because I did not know that the overlay and the game menu through Win-G (in the Russian version of Windows) are the same.

Comment: They are the same, but they are not limited to games. You can start the overlay from anything. Games, programs, etc. The only exception is the windows desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is so asinine.

You have to open the Windows Game Bar, default Windows + G

Then you have to go to the capture widget and start capturing.

While you're capturing the window will pop up and you can move it.